# How to make the values entered in a text field appear in the HTML sentence

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing an assignment where I have to make up 10 random sentences and I have to create text fields. These text fields are supposed to include whatever I put in them inside the sentences. I need help with the code that will include the words inside the sentence. I think I've figured out how to except when I type something into "name" it displays only one letter of what I input and not the whole word.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Assignment 4</title>
<h1> Assignment 4 - Sample Solution </h1>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  Name:         <input type="text" id = "input" value= "names" size="10" />
  <br />

  Verb Phrase:  <input type="text" id = "input2" value="verbs" size="10" />
  <br />

  Adjective:    <input type="text" id = "input3" value="adjs" size="10" />
  <br />

  Noun:         <input type="text" id = "input4" value="nouns" size="10" />
  <br />
HOW MANY SENTENCES? <select id = "numOfSentences" size = "1">

    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>

<button id = "displaySilly">
    Display Silly
</button>
<p id = "output"></p>
<script src = "silly.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS.

```
//arrays containing values for sentence components
var names = ["Alice","Rowena","Carol","David","Erin"];
var verbs = ["jumped on", "ran from", "scolded", "yelled at","talked to"];
var adjs  = ["yellow","big","smelly","hairy","bad"];
var nouns = ["bear","tree","rock","student","instructor"];

// variables for the sentence components
var name, verb, adj, noun; 

//when window loads
window.onload = function () {
    var names =     document.getElementById("input");
    names.value = null;
    var verbs = document.getElementById("input2");
    verbs.value= null;
    var adjs = document.getElementById("input3");
    adjs.value= null;
    var nouns = document.getElementById("input4");
    nouns.value= null;
}


// display what is put into the text fields in the sentences
//names.push(document.getElementById('input').value);
//verbs.push(document.getElementById('input2').value);
//adjs.push(document.getElementById('input3').value);
//nouns.push(document.getElementById('input4').value);

// display silly sentences 
document.getElementById('displaySilly').onclick = function() {

    var names = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = names;

    // get number of sentences from drop down
    var numOfSentences = 
        document.getElementById('numOfSentences').value;
    //convert to integer
    numOfSentences = parseInt(numOfSentences);
    // initialize results string
    var results = "";
    // create required number of silly sentences 
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= numOfSentences ; i++) {
        //pick components at random from arrays 
        name =
            names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
        verb =
            verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)];
        adj =
            adjs[Math.floor(Math.random()  * adjs.length)];
        noun =
            nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
    // concatenate to form a sentence
    // add to other sentences 
    results = results + name + " " + verb +
              " the " + adj  + " " + noun +
              ".<br />";
}


// display the silly sentences 
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = results;
} //*** END onclick handler
```

I need help with the

```
  var names = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = names;
```

Thanks guys

Comment: nope works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/cxw9pt41/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different variables with the same identifier; for instance, three variables called `names`. And near the end, when you're reading from the arrays with

```javascript
names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
```

that is not the same `names` as the array containing the names!

So the solution is to give all those `names` different names.

Comment: OK. If you want, you can click the check mark to the left, to mark this question as answered. Otherwise it will stay in the list of unanswered questions!